# Add new words to the fugashi dictionary

Tags: text-mining, mecab

I'm using fugashi to extract words from sentences.
How do I add new terms that are not in the fugacy dictionary to the dictionary?

For example, YouTube is divided into "You" and "Tube."

```
import fugashi
tagger = fugashi.Tagger()
nodes = tagger.parseToNodeList("ユーチューブ")
goodpos = ['名詞']
nodes = [nn.surface for nn in nodes if nn.feature.pos1 in goodpos]
```

=> ['ユー', 'チューブ']

Answer (score 3):

I haven't gotten around to making a proper guide for this yet, but basically you should follow the [MeCab docs](https://taku910.github.io/mecab/dic.html), but you can use `fugashi-build-dict` instead of `mecab-dict-index`.

To give brief instructions, first you need to make a CSV file that uses the same format as your system dictionary. This is based on `unidic-lite`.

```
令和,4786,4786,8205,名詞,固有名詞,一般,*,*,*,レイワ,令和,令和,レーワ,令和,レーワ,固,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,レイワ,レイワ,レイワ,レイワ,"1,0",*,*,*,*
㋿,5969,5969,2588,補助記号,一般,*,*,*,*,,㋿,㋿,,㋿,,記号,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,,,,,*,*,*,*,999999
㋿,4786,4786,3992,名詞,固有名詞,一般,*,*,*,レイワ,令和,㋿,レーワ,㋿,レーワ,固,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,レイワ,レイワ,レイワ,レイワ,"1,0",*,*,*,*
夢夢,4786,4786,8205,名詞,固有名詞,一般,*,*,*,レイワ,令和,令和,レーワ,令和,レーワ,固,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,レイワ,レイワ,レイワ,レイワ,"1,0",*,*,*,*
```

You can make this by copying entries from the UniDic source and editing fields. Then you run this command:

```
fugashi-build-dict -d dicdir/ -u mydic.dic mydic.csv
```

`dicdir` is the location of your system dictionary, `mydic.csv` is the csv file you made. This will create the `mydic.dic` file, which you can then use with fugashi by specifying `-u mydic.dic`.

Comment: Is there a guide to the fields of unidic-lite, specifically what those three numbers in the beginning are? I think [this example](https://gist.github.com/Kimtaro/ab137870ad4a385b2d79) is for IPADIC and there, the first three numbers are `left_context_id` and `right_context_id` (ok to be -1) and `cost`. Any guidance on what numbers to use for ユーチューブ?

Comment: You are right about those first three numbers - those are the same in every MeCab dictionary, see the MeCab docs for details. For the cost 100 is usually fine, for the others you need to find a similar term (part of speech, etc) in the dictionary you're using. unidic-lite is based on UniDic 2.1.2 with accent annotations.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I want to ask you one more question.
As you said, I did the command `fugashi-build-dict -d mymecabdicdir/ -u mydic.dic csvfile.csv`
However, I get `dictionary.cpp(304) [ifs] no such file or directory: utf8` error.
Modifying the `fugashi-build-dict` at the beginning of the command to `/usr/local/libexec/mecab/mecab-dict-index` will work without any problems.
I also set the fugashi version to 1.1.0. Is there a problem?

Comment: Ah, looks like `fugashi-build-dict` had a bug and didn't work. Pushed a fix and will release soon. Also in general don't follow up on Stack Overflow in comments like this, it's hard to follow, please just open an issue at Github. https://github.com/polm/fugashi

Comment: This tweet has an explanation of the columns.  https://twitter.com/zakki/status/920977351059554304